# Printing excel file programmatically

Tags: .net, excel, c#-4.0, printing

I face a problem on my application , I have a long running process , one of its outputs should be an excel file which has to be printed in background . 
The process will get a data from the remote server , and it has a predefined excel template then all I have to do to create the excel file and send it to the printer .
I founded the ExcelPackage project and NOPI project which deals with excel files .

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the excel sheet programmatically and then use p/invoke ShellExecute with the "print" operation and the filename:

MSDN ShellExecute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

P/Invoke ShellExecute: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/ShellExecute.html

This will call the installed Excel version and tell it to open and print the given file on the default printer. Excel will close automatically after printing.

Comment: This is the big issue . Sorry , I didn't mention that , I don't have excel installed on the machines the process installed on ?